# Google Chrome Developer Tool Content Downloaded Time

Tags: performance, google-chrome

We are facing performance issue in our web application to load page in colorbox.
From server side we know some sql calls need to be improved , however there is also one point of concern as shown in below image 'Content Download' Time is more than 250 ms , The page we are downloading have tabular data and not too much of css.

[image]

My question is - 
1.In general how long it should take to download content ? 
2.What could be the area of improvement at client side ?

Comment: When we submit the form and its succesfull , we return the same jsp which takes longer time to load , so what I did is instead of same jsp I returned and empty jsp and in that inside jquery call I close my popup window. It worked in a fraction of second.